# Problema com data!

Tags: php

Tenho esse trecho de código:

```
if ($informations->fundation_date != $dateFoundation) {
    echo 'estou no echo diferente do date';
    $alter .= 'fundation_date/';
} else {
    echo 'esta igual date';
}

echo'data antiga: '.$informations->fundation_date;
echo'data nova: '.$dateFoundation;
```

Uso banco de dados Postgree; estou comparando se a data mudou ou não no *input*, mas mesmo quando não altero a data ela vem diferente. Pois no banco (fundation_date) vem como 1995-05-11 e já no *input* 05/11/1995. Como posso fazer, mas que elas sejam iguais quando for assim?

Comment: Quando grava no banco de dados, tem que gravar com o formato yyyy-mm-dd. Quando for gravar no banco de dados trate a data como uma string manipulando-a pra ficar dessa forma.

Comment: veja isso: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php
tem como fazer a manipulação da data. quando a guardar no banco de dados guarde como formato que pretende.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar duas funções em conjunto: *date()* e *strtotime()*.

```
$dateFoundation = $_POST['data'];
$dateFoundation = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateFoundation));

if($informations->fundation_date != $dateFoundation){
   echo "Diferente!";
}
else{
   echo "Igual!";
}
```

Comment: isso nao resolve a questão uma vez que mesmo quando nao altera a data ela vem diferente. tem que tratar a string de forma a que fique igual, só isso.

Comment: Então responde aí, @LuísAlmeida. Falar que não resolve, muita gente fala.

Comment: calma cara. só tentei esclarecer que o que vc escreveu esta correcto mas nao resolve o problema. comentei na pergunta dela ... talvez ajude. :) abr

Comment: @Gumball eu tentei aqui e acabou dando erro na função strtotime().

Comment: Que erro deu ? Edita sua pergunta e coloca...

Comment: @Gumball funcionou como você falou agora! Muito obrigada.